# Enable/Disable Outlook Addin Programmatically

Tags: outlook, outlook-2013

I have created Add-in for outlook 2013.

I wanted to on / off other addin. So I have used below code to do that.

```
Outlook.Application OutLook = new Outlook.Application();

if (OutLook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect)
{
 OutLook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = false;
}
else
{
OutLook.Application.COMAddIns.Item("OutlookAddIn").Connect = true;
}
```

But it is working fine, only if I open outlook as administrator. For normal user, it is not working fine.

So is there any other way I can achieve this? or I can run only this code as admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a local admin or a power user to be able to modify HKLM. A normal user doesn't have sufficient privileges for modifying the [windows registry keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx)  for the add-in. Most probably the add-in was registeredin the HKLM hive, am I right?

Of course, for a per-machine add-in, you can set the Connect property if your application is run with administrative permissions. But on a system with UAC enabled, in addition to having administrative permissions, the application process must be elevated.

You can disable the add-in manually in Outlook, even a per-machine add-in. It means that you can add a HKCU entry to get it done. If I look at the registry, the value of 'LoadBehavior' of the Addin  under HKEY_CURRENT_USER has changed. But the value of 'LoadBehavior' under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE has not changed.  This is expected behavior - normal user can't disable the Addin for all users.

Be aware, in that case the add-in will be disabled for the current user only.

That is why I'd suggest disabling all features of your add-in at runtime instead of trying to turn it off. At runtime you can check whether a user is authorized to load your add-in or not, based on the authentication results you can decide whether to load the add-in's UI and other business logic (subscribe to Outlook events and etc.) or not. I.e. the add-in will be enabled, but the end user will not notice that.

Even if you add the LoadBehavior key to the corresponding HKCU hive, the add-in will be loaded next time Outlook is started.

Comment: yes, you are right. My add-in is registered in the HKLM hive only. can we do something so that the add-in will be disabled for the current user only. please send me some example if you have.

Comment: There is no any sample project. The actual solution depends on your needs: disable the add-in UI or add HKCU key temporarily.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Again there are two problems. 1)How to create HKCU key temporary. 2)  Is it possible to disable custom context menu Ribbon UI.

Comment: 1. You can use .Net classes for working with windows registry keys. 2. Yes, it is. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: Now it is working fine. But have a look at one more case: I have to disable ribbon button as well as Custom task pane. So after  myRibbon.Invalidate(); method, i am setting custom task pane visibility to false. and it is working. but if i toggle my button, then on each toggle - it is firing my other button event.