# How to make my Outlook Add-in Automatically activated in outlook?

Tags: c#, installation, add-in, outlook-addin

I have created an Outlook Add-in using c# and when i install it using an MSI file on a computer it doesn't automatically activate in outlook. I have to manually go into Outlook Settings and turn it on. How can I make my c# windows installer or my add-in program made in c# to automatically enable the plugin in outlook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable Outlook Addin Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836370/enable-disable-outlook-addin-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps to install your add-in. This example is for excel but change the registry to Outlook and it will be fine. The key of LoadBehavior 3 means load at startup

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Useful link, thnx